# Select a user from table where the user isn't logged in and not a part of another tables rows

Tags: mysql

What I have is two tables: users and contacts.

In users I have a 'username' and a few other columns but they are unimportant for the query.

In contacts I have 'SUsername' and 'RUsername'.

The purpose of this is when a user is logged in they can search for other users and add them. When they add them the logged in username is added to the RUsername column and the added user is inserted into SUsername.

However the problem arises when I go to list users. The logic is: List all users as long as they aren't the user that is logged in "$Session_Username", also make sure it doesn't show any username where $Session_Username is present in either SUsername or RUsername from the contacts table. Seeing as they are already connected to this person. The reason I have to check both is because someone may add me or I may add someone and that dictates the placement in RUsername or SUsername.

I have tried numerous ways to make it work but I only get partial working queries. The best one is this one:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE (Username != '$Session_Username' AND Username != (SELECT SUsername FROM contacts WHERE RUsername = '$Session_Username')) OR
(Username != '$Session_Username' AND Username != (SELECT RUsername FROM contacts WHERE SUsername = '$Session_Username'))
;";
```

This works when there is a row in the contacts table containing $Session_Username in RUsername. However if I login as a user that isn't present in the contacts table in any way it returns empty. I also would need to add

```
"Username != '$Session_Username'"
```

Somewhere in the query too for those that don't have an entry in contacts. But when I go to add this in anyway it kills the query once it runs and doesn't perform the other two. I have tried many combinations of AND + OR but I cannot seem to get the logic right.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are these SQL strings for PHP? Are you interpolating PHP variables directly into an SQL string?  If yes, please have a read of [Why you Should be using PHP's PDO for Database Access](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) and [PHP Database Access: Are You Doing It Correctly?](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard query in a social media site. It is a lot easier if you use `union`, rather than a complicated `where` clause:

```
select u1.*
from users u1
left join
    (select susername as username from contacts where rusername=...
     union all
     select rusername from contacts where susername=...
    ) t on u1.username=t.username
 where t.username is null and u1.username <> ...
```

Susbstitute the username from the session in place of the `...`

Alternatively, you can use `not exists` subqueries because you do not want to fetch any data from the `contacts` table.

```
select u1.*
from users u1
where not exists (select 1 from contacts where susername=... and rusername=u1.username)
  and not exists (select 1 from contacts where rusername=... and susername=u1.username)
  and username=...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still very much a novice at mysql but this helped so much and makes a lot of sense! For those that come across this, this is what I used:

    "SELECT u1.* FROM users u1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM contacts WHERE SUsername='$Session_Username' AND RUsername=u1.Username) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM contacts WHERE RUsername='$Session_Username' AND SUsername=u1.Username) AND Username !='$Session_Username'";